# How to display sub categories on individual pages?

Tags: categories

I currently have a summary page that displays the links to 5 product categories (with a product image for each category) - the user clicks on an image is taken to a new page that displays all the products in that category.

What I now need to do is have a new product category (c6) with 3 sub-categories (c6-a), with each of these sub-categories potentially have multiple sub-categories (c6-a-1).

c6 > c6-a/c6-b/c6-c > c6-a-1/c6-a-2/c6-a-3 ...etc

The problem I'm having is getting EE to display the categories inside the 1st level of sub-category (c6-a) on a single page.  So that the user can select c6 from the top level of product categories, & then see the c6-a/c6-b/c6-c sub-categories displayed on a new page, and then click from that selection to see a single page displaying the products in, for example, the c6-a-1 sub-category (and then choose a product to view).

There would also need to be a breadcrumb trail at the top of each page...

Any help with this would be very much appreciated!!!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [**GWcode Categories**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories) addon should get you what you need.

> You basically pick a starting point first to get a list of categories and then narrow it down by choosing from a wide variety of parameters. Your starting point can be:>
>
> - One or more channels by using the channel parameter (to get the categories for those channels);
> - One or more category groups by using the group_id parameter (to get the categories for those category groups);
> - An entry (to get the categories the entry has been added to);
> - ***A category (to get its child categories, or parent categories).***

Answer (score 2):

The [GWcode CatMenu](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-catmenu) might fit the bill a little better. It dynamically creates multi-level navigation menus. I was trying to do the same thing a couple weeks ago with conditionals for GWcode Categories and realized this plugin did exactly what I needed out of the box. Look at the examples on the site for different solutions.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply Siebird - I had got stuck trying to do this with GWcode Categories...  So will definitely try again GWcode CatMenu.  Thanks.